# Nullable object must have a value when including a grandchild with a null child

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

We are currently running into an issue with Entity Framework where we are grabbing something from the database that has a child element that can be null and also try to include the grandchild.

Example

```
var workItems = _context.WorkItems
            .Include(x => x.Contract)
            .Include(x => x.Contract.ContractAccount)
```

If contract is null (which is allowed) then when it tries to include ContractAccount it fails due to Contract being null.

So far we've tried putting a null check against the child inside the grandchild.

i.e

```
Contract ?? null : ContractAccount
```

We've also tried using

```
DefaultIfEmpty(new Contract())
```

which also doesn't seem to be allowed.

We need to return the full WorkItem and its contract/contractaccount if it has one back to the user but if there isn't a contract then it should just return the WorkItem.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ThenInclude`:

```
var workItems = _context.WorkItems
        .Include(x => x.Contract)
        .ThenInclude(contract => contract.ContractAccount);
```

Comment: Hi, we're using EF6 not EF Core so ThenInclude is not available.

Comment: Yeah, all working now. Would be interested to know if there's a solution without a third party library but accepting your answer as it has solved our issue. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

in place of `Contract ?? null : ContractAccount`
try like

```
 Contract.HasValue ? Contract.Value: defaultValue
```

According to **`C# Nullable`** Documentation If a value of type T has not been assigned to the Nullable object, you can compare it to null and retrieve its HasValue property, but you cannot access its Value property or call its other members.

[you can check  Nullable Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.value?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Nullable_1_Value)

Comment: Hi,This doesn't seem to be usable inside a .Include.   .Include(c=> c.Contract.HasValue) gives error that HasValue is not a method of Contract.